# Warning while opening pdf file in java

Tags: java, pdf

I populate a form in PDF using my java program. I am using faceless library for pdf read/write. I keep getting this warning

```
Annotation 1/175 on page 1 is part of another PDF's form - removing
```

I tried compressing the pdf, but it hasn't helped. Does anyone know if they have faced similar problem and what they did to remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not used Faceless, but from their [faq](http://bfo.com/faq.jsp) and [user manual](http://bfo.com/products/pdf/docs/userguide.pdf) I can gather this much:

The error message (PG1) you are getting means this:

> Annotation is part of another PDF's
>   form. The opposite of FE2, this occurs
>   when in the situation described for
>   FE2, you try and render document B.
>   It's saying that a widget on this page
>   is actually the widget for a field in
>   another document. Since a Widget has
>   to have a field, we're not going to
>   render it and it gets deleted.

FE2, which is refered to here means this:

> Annotation for field is on another
>   PDF's page. Like the error above, but
>   this normally occurs when you've been
>   moving pages around between documents.
>   If document A has a page and one form
>   field with an annotation on that page,
>   and then you move the page to document
>   B, when you try and render document A,
>   your form element has an annotation on
>   page no longer in the document. Like
>   FE1, this warning is thrown and the
>   annotation removed.

It seems like this is also related to:

> In version 2.0, if you want to copy a
>   form field annotation from one
>   document to another you need to move
>   the FormElement associated with it
>   separately.

Without seeing more of your code, however, it is very hard to figure out what exactly is wrong. Update your question with some relevant code snippets, and we can work from there.